# How to create Managed Metadata Column & Mapping It With Termset

Tags: managed-metadata, site-column

I'm trying to create Department Managed Metadata Column using visual studio.

I have to mapped that column to Department tearmset under people group.

[image]

I have found some articles on google. but they are confusing for me.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this blog to create managed meta data Site column using visual studio and map the term set to that field in feature activation method.

[Creating a Site Column with managed Metadata](https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2013/04/01/creating-a-site-column-with-managed-metadata/)